# What is meant by "quarter = half" when changing tempo?

Tags: theory, tempo, meter

What is meant by the following indications when changing tempo:

" In 4 quarter = 126"

and later

"In 2 quarter = half"

Answer (score 5):

We may miss some details depending on the particular musical example, but in general these indications are telling you two things: the meter and the tempo.

> In 4 quarter = 126

This is saying that the meter is "in 4"; in other words, you should conceptualize each measure as having four beats. Furthermore, the quarter note will appear at a tempo of 126 beats per minute (bpm). If you're in 4/4 time, just put a metronome at 126 and that will be every beat of the measure.

> In 2 quarter = half

This is saying that the meter is "in 2"; there are only two large beats in each measure. Furthermore, it says that the tempo of the new half note is equivalent to the the tempo of the prior quarter note. Assuming this indication comes right after the previous one, this is saying that the new half note is equal to 126 beats per minute.